# Eclipse 4 Configure binding of dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

At my company we're used to building Eclipse plugins that shares interfaces with command line tools. We're investigating using the Eclipse 4 RCP API for our next plugins, but I have trouble using injection on our own objects. For example I'd like to declare that IHelper must be instantiated by EclipseHelper:

```java
interface IHelper { /* In core plugin (not Eclipse dependent) */
  ...
}

class EclipseHelper implements IHelper { /* In Eclipse plugin */
  @Inject
  EclipseHelper(IWorkbench workbench) { ... }
}
```

With guice I would declare in the Injector a binding from IHelper to EclipseHelper but with Eclipse I only find snippets (as on [vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextUsage/article.html#ownobjects_difrom)) to bind IHelper to a *concrete instance* of EclipseHelper. I don't want to do that, constructing the instance can be arbitrarily complicated. How can I declare the binding - at the application level  - ?

Comment: The methods described in the vogella article are all there is.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse DI in an OSGi environment? If so you can use a ContextFunction to solve this. If the DI Container doesn't find an appropriate instance for IHelper it will look through the OSGi services. If it also doesn't find an OSGi service for IHelper it will look for a ContextFunction to produce one.

Comment: Yes we are: we ship plugins on top of xtext or the CDT. But if you understood vogella's article about context functions (https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextFunctions/article.html#examples-for-context-function-registrations) right, I would need to declare the binding in OSGI-INF/views.xml; which seemed inconvenient. I'd prefer using code only.

For the moment I resorted to this in my Activactor's start method : InjectorFactory.getDefault().addBinding(IHelper.class).implementedBy(EclipseHelper.class) but I wonder if it'll scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse DI in an OSGi Environment (and since you are trying to inject `IWorkbench` i assume that you are), you can use a `ContextFunction` to produce an instance if it's not available in the IEclipseContext.

This will put the ContextFunction in the OSGi service layer:

```
@Component(service = IContextFunction.class, property = "service.context.key=my.domain.IHelper")
public class IHelperFactoryCF extends ContextFunction {
    @Override
    public Object compute(IEclipseContext context) {
        return ContextInjectionFactory.make(EclipseHelper.class, context);
    }
}
```

You could also put the `ContextFunction` in the DI-Context.
See here for more information: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Contexts#Context_Functions